# displaying in textarea after split() and substring() of input array

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea

html code:

```
<textarea id="TaAll" rows=11>
 </textarea>

<input type="button" Value="Get Results" 
 onclick="doit();"/>

<textarea id="Tanext" rows=11>
  </textarea>
```

javascript code:

```
window.doit = function ()
{
console.log(document.getElementById("TAall").value);
var containertext=document.getElementById("TAall").value.split("\n");  
    for(var i=0;i< containertext.length;i++)
      {
       var temp=containertext[i+1].split(" "); 
       sbray[i]=eval(temp[1].substring(1,temp[1].length)); 
       op[i]=eval(temp[2].substring(1,temp[2].length)); 


       } 
 Tb = document.frmone.Tanext;


 Tb.value = Tb.value +("\n")+sbray.join("\n")+ ("\n")+"Test";




keysbyValue(); 
}
```

hi, in the above code, i have 2 text areas. i am writing input in TAall textarea and split it and save substrings of it in other arrays sbray[] and op[]. the code till displaying containertext[] in textarea works fine but when i am trying to display resulting  sbray[] in other textarea Tbnext it doesnot work. the inputs i am using is as follows and i have to use inputs in this format. i want to split the array and  save substring of all the no. appended with left "c" in sbray[] and right "c" in op[]:

```
10
1 c1 c2 //i want to save and split the array starting from this line.
2 c3 c4
3 c5 c12
4 c6 c7
5 c8 c11
6 c9 c10
7 c13 c15
8 c14 c16
9 c17 c18
10 c19 c20
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's not working?  Error messages?  Output?  Just saying "it doesnot work" is inadequate for getting help here.

Comment: hi, it is not displaying the sbray[] in other text area.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById is **case-sensitive**.  Your `<textarea>`'s id is `TaAll` but you are trying to get it by `document.getElementById("TAall")`

Comment: thanks for your reply, Andrey i corrected the mistake but it still doesnt work

Comment: i tried all the above suggestions. checked all the links. thanks for that but the code still doesnt work. it should display sbray[] in Tanext textarea, which it doesnot

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` is case sensitive, change `TAall` to `TaAll`, and it should work way better.

There is also some other mistakes, you shouldn't use eval, because the scope to temp is lost for example.

I tried to make your script works, you can check its behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/KjYpX/

Edit:

I finally understand what you wanted, you can try the script here: http://jsfiddle.net/KjYpX/1/
It is made in a less dirty way.

Here the detail of the function to parse your weird format:

```
var parseMyFormat = function(input){ // we declare a new function
  var sbray=[], op=[]; // declaration of two temporary array
  (input=input.split('\n')).shift(); // we split input in an array called input containing all lines, and then we shift it, it means we remove the first element.

  while(o=input.shift()){ // now, we are gonna make a loop, shift remove the first element but also return it, so we save it in the o variable
    sbray.push((o = o.match(/c(\d+) c(\d+)$/))[1]); //we apply a regexp on o to get the two decimal (\d) ids, it returns an array containing for example ['c1 c2','c1','c2'], we save this array in o (because we will not use o anymore), and we push 'c1' in sbray
    op.push(o[2]); // we push 'c2' in op
  }

  return [sbray, op]; // finally we return both arrays so that you can access them easily
}
```

Comment: my script doesnot still work. i tried everything you guys suggested. i dont understand why it is not displaying anything.

Comment: Have you tried to go to he link I gave you, and enter your list in the textbox in the bottom righ area of jsfiddle where there are your two textarea, then hit "Get Results" and results appears in the other textarea. It's not what you wanted ? In fact what do you want exactly as Output ? We can't really help you, if you don't explain what you want as output ;).

Comment: i tried all the suggestions given by all of you. Tronix 117 i want to thanks you for ur help but the link u provided doesnot work with me. there are 2 text boxes. i want to enter strings in the first textbox on left. i specified the input above. then i want to split and save substrings of the input in sbray[] and op[] arrays, in the end display these arrays in the textbox on the right.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want in the second textarea, could you please edit your post, and add the desire output, like you made for the input ? (Even if you don't put all the lines).

Comment: output: 1 /n 3 /n 5 /n 6 /n..... this should be be the values displayed. these are the values taken from the input. if u look at for example:  1 c2 c5 . this is my input. i am splitting it in temp[0],temp[1] and temp[2]. for example temp[1]= c2 temp[2]=c5. now i further use substring and save 2 from c2 in sbray[0] and 5 from c5 in op[0]. this goes on. in the end of for loop i should have sbray[containertext.length-1] and op[containertext.length-1]. i want to display sbray[] and op[] in the 2nd text area.

Comment: Check my post, I edited it in order to match your expectation, you can also find the working script here: http://jsfiddle.net/KjYpX/1/

Answer (score 0):

You passed `TAall` to `document.getElementById`, but the `id` is `TaAll`. You will get an error, as the object you asked for doesn't exist.

Also, you are iterating from `0` to `containertext.length-1`, but you are asking for `containertext[i+1]`. As the biggest index in an array is `array.length-1` (0-based indexing), `containertext[containertext.length]` gives error.